# How can I implement the code display style in StackOverflow?

Tags: html, css

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

I have a line of code ( which is to long to be displayed in one line ) to be displayed on a web page in one line, just like above.

I don't it to be wrapped into two lines.

Can I accomplish this only using css?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To actually make this happen when you use words with spaces in between them `overflow:auto` is not enough, you'll also need `text-overflow: nowrap`.

http://jsfiddle.net/kZV3j/

Answer (score 3):

Here's how SO's code block looks:

```
<pre>
  <code>
    <span>...</span>
  </code>
</pre>
```

And the CSS:

```
pre {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TfeLm/**

Comment: overflow without a specified with won't work... (and that `span` is not good)

Comment: I beg to differ? Before parsing HTML and CSS in your head, at least test it: http://jsfiddle.net/TfeLm/

Comment: you're right. The pre element has a default `width:100%;` so it works.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for `overflow:auto`:

```
<div style="overflow:auto; width:200px;">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
```

Comment: Downvote for using inline CSS? It's a quick example. It works fine. I'm not suggesting to code an entire project using inline CSS.

Comment: Yes, quick example or not avoid using inline CSS. An answer need to show a good way of doing it, not an quick and dirty example

Comment: [When should I vote down?](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down) - Is my answer egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended, or clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

Create a containing element (e.g. a div), then set some basic CSS properties on it that define a width, and handle the overflow. Like this:

HTML

```
<div class="short">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>​
```

CSS:

```
.short {
    width:400px;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow-x:scroll;
}​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/6qJYr/)**. Works in all modern browsers and IE8.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the [`overflow`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visufx.html#overflow) property with a `auto` value:

```
<style>pre { width: 200px; overflow: auto; }</style>
<pre><code>&lt;p&gt;Some tooooo long text on one line&lt;/&gt;</code></pre>
```

Live example: http://jsbin.com/uhuveg/

Comment: Your example does not show a scrollbar (at least not in Firefox).

Comment: It does in IE, so I thought it worked on every browser :) I think the problem is answered [by stephan muller](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10092046/1149495)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you should use the following CSS

```
#id {
    width: 400px;
    padding: 5px;
    background: #C3C3C3;
    overflow-x: scroll
}​
```

See this live [example](http://jsfiddle.net/jackdent/hDJqB/)